# Can't understand the last part of this code - Dart

Tags: dart

```
List<Person> persons = fromMap([{"id": 1, "name": "John Doe"}], [() => List<Person>, Person]);
```

I can't understand the part after the second comma. Can anyone explain it to me pls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[() => List<Person>, Person]`

This is specifying the `type` of the object that is going to be created, so, the first part is `List<Person>`, this will be same as the resultant object, of course, then, the next argument tells the type of the elements inside the object that will be created that is Person.

We need to do this because Dart is dynamically typed, doesn't care what the object is. But, if you need the code to run properly, so, you do care what the type is.

Comment: Would it be a problem if I just write Person instead of ```[() => List<Person>, Person]``` ?

Comment: Yes, of course, as the resultant object is not of the Person.

Comment: Think of it, recursive type defining, if that resonates.

Comment: What if I put List<Person> instead?

Comment: You need to go to the end. You need to define the whole hierarchy, otherwise it will raise Error.

Comment: So, we're saying Convert List<Map> to List<List<Person>> ?

Comment: Dart *can* be dynamically typed, but it also can be statically typed.

Comment: Yes, that is what that code is doing, bro. You are specifying types here. So, it is statically typed.